# When doing Pandas DataFrame Calculations top row returns all zeros and all other rows correct

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a function that takes a dataframe and concatenates a second dataframe next to the original dataframe with a simple calculation of percentages. I want to have the rows simply be values followed by percentages. Here is an example:

```
A,   B,   A (%),   B (%)
1,   1,    0.50,     0.50  
1,   1,    0.50,     0.50
```

But instead my code is returning:

```
A,   B,   A (%),   B (%)
1,   1,     0 ,      0  
1,   1,    .50 ,    .50
```

The first row in and sized dataframe that I do this with returns a row of zeros and then the calculations that follow in later rows are all correct. The code I am running deals with a dataframe that has 3 columns containing values... Count, IV, P are their titles. 
I have attached the code below:

```
    column_list = []
for column in frame.columns[1:]:
    column_list.append(column + ' (%)')

percentages = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_list)
for i in range(frame.shape[0]):
    percentages.loc[i] = [float(frame.iloc[i,1])/float(frame['Count'].sum()), 
float(frame.iloc[i,2])/float(frame['IV'].sum()), 
float(frame.iloc[i,3])/float(frame['P'].sum())]

return_frame = pd.concat([frame,percentages], axis = 1)


return return_frame
```

Comment: For input `df` dataframe - this should `df.join((df/df.sum()).add_suffix(' (%%)'))` work I suppose?

Comment: Are you looking for the percentage over the rows or the columns? If `frame.loc[0, 'B']` was 2, would you be aiming to have `frame.loc[0, 'A (%)']` be 0.5 or 0.333?

Comment: I was trying to get the percentages over the columns, sorry the example I provided did not make that clear.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where the bug in your code is, but here is a concise way to achieve your desired output:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 3], 'B': [9, 7]})
df_percent = df.apply(lambda r: r/sum(r), axis=1).add_suffix('( %%)')
df_result = pd.concat([df, df_percent], axis=1)
```

Contents of `df_result`:

```
   A  B  A (%)  B (%)
0  1  9    0.1    0.9
1  3  7    0.3    0.7
```

Also, you may want to multiply the `df_percent` values by 100 to convert what are technically fractions into percentages.

**EDIT:** To get column-wise percentages instead of row-wise, change `axis=1` to `axis=0`. The contents of `df_result` is then:

```
   A  B  A( %)   B( %)
0  1  9   0.25  0.5625
1  3  7   0.75  0.4375
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but the way that I want to calculate the values is a little bit different. I want to have it calculate the percentage of the column, so it would look more like this 

(0,0) = .25   (0,1) =  .5625
(1,0) = .75   (1,1) =   .4375

Comment: @JamesRacanelli Ah, I see! Simply change `axis=1` to `axis=0`.